# Getting 404 when loading dynamic routes on nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I make a dynamic route like [results].js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { results } = router.query;

    return <p>Post: {results}</p>
}

export default Post
```

and configure my next.confi.js

```
module.exports = {
    trailingSlash: true,
}
```

It's working well on dev mode but in production mode, I have the only problem with the dynamic page route after npm run export.When I browse htttps://my-domain/search/searchslog
it's getting 404 error page.

Comment: Next.js uses a file base routing. What is your directory structure?

Comment: My directory structure is-

search/[result].js

Comment: @TanjeebAhsan were you trying to deploy this to Cloudflare Pages?

Answer (score 0):

`next export` will pre-render all pages and export your app as static HTML. For your dynamic route, you'll need to use [`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation) to let Next.js know which HTML pages to generate for that route.

```js
// pages/search/[results].js

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [
            { params: { results: 'result1' } },
            { params: { results: 'result2' } }
        ],
        fallback: false
  };
}
```

The function above will generate `/search/result1` and `/search/result2` pages. Any other `/serach/*` page will result in a 404.

Comment: I tried something like below for search from 

    ```<input className="text-field" type="text"  value={this.state.userName} onChange={event => this.setState({userName: event.target.value})}/>
       <a href={'/search/'+this.state.userName} className="search-button"></a>```

There have some conditions on [result].js if the search key match with fetch API data.It's working on dev mode but I for production is show 404.

Comment: You can't really use a statically generated dynamic route page like that. All possible search routes (`/search/*`) need to be pre-rendered at build time for them not to 404. Try using the query param in the URL to pass the search term instead (`/search?key=value`).

Comment: I need a URL `www.domain-name.com/search-any-keys` something like that for the search result. What will be the component design for that?